# error : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am getting this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

```
int a = 2;
int[] nt = new int[100], d = new int[100];
d[0] = nt[0] = 3;
d[1] = nt[1] = 5;
for (int i = 7; i < 100; i += a)
{
    for (int j = 0; nt[j] < i; j++)
    {
        if (d[j] != 0)
        {
            d[j]--;
        }
        else
        {
            d[j] = nt[j];
            //  -->error: nt[k]<i
            for (int k = j + 1; nt[k] < i; k++)
```

Can you help me fix the code?

Comment: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`? That's C# not C, isn't it? And please post the whole code, not just a snippet.

Comment: `int[] nt = new int[100], d = new int[100];
` It isn't `C`...

Comment: How do you prevent `k` to become `100` or larger? If such a limitation exist, it would be in the code below the snippet you show us. If it doesn't exist, that's the reason for your error.

Comment: Try to refactor your code to be a bit more sensible, that'll make debugging this problem A LOT easier.

Answer (score 0):

The last line is missing the range test for `k`. If there is no `nt[k]` less than `i`, then `k` will grow out of bounds, i.e. it will eventually become greater or equal 100.

```
for (int k = j + 1; k < 100 && nt[k] < i; k++)
```

Since C# uses short circuit evaluation, the test `k < 100 && nt[k] < i` evaluates the second part `nt[k] < i` only if the first part `k < 100` is `true`. This prevents accessing a `nt` with an index greater or equal 100.

See also:

- [Conditional logical AND operator &&](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-), (C# Reference)
- [Conditional logical OR operator ||](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-), (C# Reference)

---

`100` in your code is a **magic number**. Declare a constant for it.

```
const int N = 100;

int[] nt = new int[N];
...
for (int k = j + 1; k < N && nt[k] < i; k++)
```

But I don't know the context of your code. You might have a better name for it than `N`.

See: [Writing Clean Code and Magic Numbers](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b7dc95/writing-clean-code-and-magic-numbers/) (C# Corner).